# Possibly a bug or only a new behavior using "background-color" with `DT`

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

Since version `v0.26` the `background-color` has changed for the package `DT` used in R `shiny`. Is this the same for you and my question, is it a bug that changing the background-color does not work anymore?!

```
library(shiny)

testUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(NS(id, "mytable")),
    verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "selected"))
  )
}

testServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session,data) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, selection = list(mode = "multiple", target = "row"))

    output$selected <- renderPrint(
      input$mytable_rows_selected  # Caution: The prefix must match the id of my namespace
    )

  })
}

testApp <- function(install_version = c("v0.25", "v0.26"), change_background_color = FALSE) {

  stopifnot(is.logical(change_background_color))

  install_version <- match.arg(install_version)

  if (install_version == "v0.25") {
    remotes::install_github("rstudio/DT", ref = "v0.25", force = TRUE, upgrade = TRUE)
  } else {
    remotes::install_github("rstudio/DT", ref = "v0.26", force = TRUE, upgrade = TRUE)
  }

  ui <- fluidPage(

    if (isTRUE(change_background_color)) {
      tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: #FC8995 !important;}'))  # red color
    },

    testUI("test")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    testServer("test")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

**DT Version v0.25 without and with changing the background-color:**

```
testApp(install_version = "v0.25", change_background_color = FALSE)
testApp(install_version = "v0.25", change_background_color = TRUE)
```

[image]

**DT Version v0.26 without and with changing the background-color:**

```
testApp(install_version = "v0.26", change_background_color = FALSE)
testApp(install_version = "v0.26", change_background_color = TRUE)
```

[image]

**Summary:**

- Has the default `background-color` of selected rows really changed from version `v0.25` to `v0.26`?
- Why is changing the default `background-color` in version `v0.26` not working anymore?

Comment: You are changing the background color of the selected rows, and it seems to work. Maybe I don't get the question...

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok. It's possible because the JavaScript library has been updated. For your second question I didn't take a look yet.

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you have some time to check!

Comment: Done. Use the inspector tools of the browser when you don't know (that's how I did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color of the selected rows in the new version is not set with the `background-color` property: it is set with the [box-shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSREF/css3_pr_box-shadow.php) property.
Here is how to change the background color of the selected rows:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- "
table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px #FC8995 !important;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(css)),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you assume that this is an intentional change or a bug in `DT`. In the CSS the `background-color` still exists, but is overwritten by the `box-shadow` setting. Therefore, the default color has changed and the color modification has no effect any more.